# how to restart a django app through fcgi

Tags: python, django, fastcgi

we run a django app on our server through this command.

`python manage.py runfcgi host=127.0.0.1 port=8070 pidfile=/home/ubuntu/autoleg_webapp/autoleg_clients.pid --settings=PROD_Settings`

I have made some changes to PROD_Settings.py file,i want to restart now, how would i do that?

Comment: `kill -1 \`cat /home/ubuntu/autoleg_webapp/autoleg_clients.pid\``

Answer (score 2):

Tour processe's PID is in the pidfile, so you should basically kill this PID.

To do so, execute the following in your shell:

```
kill `cat /home/ubuntu/autoleg_webapp/autoleg_clients.pid`
```

Thanks to the backticks, your shell will replace `cat home/ubuntu/autoleg_webapp/autoleg_clients.pid` with the PID that's in the file.